# Azure Data Warehouse Materialized view has problem when we create dacpac file in Visual studio 2019

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I have created a database project using the target as Azure SQL Datawarehouse in Visual Studio 2019 by importing the database. When I click on build it throws me an error for Materialized views

> Error:  SQL71640: COUNT_BIG(a) is required when using this tool to
> create a materialized view that has SUM(a) in the SELECT list.

Since this is already present in the Datawarehouse it should not create an issue while creating a dacpac file and I have COUNT_BIG(*) in my script.
Can you let me know if anyone has faced similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced a similar issue and this is currently a feature of VS2019 and have received the following errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     SQL71640: Cannot create a materialized view in this tool with
> COUNT(a). Replace it with
> COUNT_BIG(a). yourProjectName yourViewName.sql
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     SQL71640: COUNT_BIG(a) is required when using this tool to
> create a materialized view that has SUM(a) in the SELECT
> list. yourProjectName yourViewName.sql

I've just updated to version 16.10.0 today and it's still an issue.  The simple workaround is to as the error suggests and convert any `COUNT` to `COUNT_BIG` as the error suggests.  The tool *may* get updated in the future so keep an eye out for updates.

As an alternative you could start to manage your materialized views in the post-deployment scripts (untested) but then you would lose the nice dependency features of SSDT.

If you feel strongly about it you could raise a feedback item here and get some upvotes for it:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-azure-synapse-analytics